# mysql split field value and check condition with two fields

Tags: mysql, split, conditional-statements

I have table with two column values like this,

```
Question             Answer
---------            -------
10#9                 yes#no
10#2                 no#yes
10#9                 yes#no
18#10                yes#no
16#1                 peter#roy
11#2                 simon#yes
```

I have to find the occurrence of question id 10 with answer yes

query like

select count(*) from table name where id= 10 and answer='yes'**

Is it possible?

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` in mysql to split the values. Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index Example how to split value http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/9058 Hope you got your needed hints..

Comment: Why do you store your data in this way?  Why not split those strings into separate columns, of appropriate data types?

Comment: @eggyal: Bcoz the table has lacks of records, and been designed b4 coming to me...:(

Comment: @Rajasekar It seems as if it would be extremely simple to modify that table. Taking the approach of saying "that is the way someone left it for me, so I'm not going to change it" is REALLY, REALLY, REALLY bad in software development.

Comment: @Mike yes, but if you start changing, the entire system need to be revised, even the client would never accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM tablename
WHERE (Question LIKE CONCAT(value, '%') AND Answer LIKE 'yes%') OR  (Question LIKE CONCAT('%', value) AND Answer LIKE '%yes')